# How to set headless = Flase in scrapy-playwright?

Tags: scrapy, playwright, playwright-python

In scrapy-playwright, how to set "headless = False". I am trying something like this.

```
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url, 
            callback = self.parse, 
            meta= dict(
                    playwright = True,
                    playwright_include_page = True,
                    playwright_page_coroutines = [
                    PageCoroutine("click", selector = "//input[@name='typeAheadInputField']"),
                    
                            ]
                        )
        )
        return super().start_requests()

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

## settings.py

```
PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS = {"headless": False}
```